# jmDNS documentation/samples

Tags: java, jmdns

Does anyone know where to find official documentation (other than the Java docs) and samples for jmDNS?

Have already search on google, the project site, sources, and have found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only documentation I've been able to find online is for an older release on SourceForge.  (The current release on GitHub is 3.5.1 and the SourceForge documentation is for 3.4.1.)

http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/jmdns/package-summary.html

It seems like up-to-date documentation disappeared when the project moved from SourceForge to GitHub, but the GitHub readme does have a short example:

https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns/blob/master/README.md

Also, here are some useful examples that helped me in my usage of JmDNS:

http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html

[Android - jmdns doesn't discover devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805893/android-jmdns-doesnt-discover-devices)

[How To Make JmDNS Work On A Large Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255329/how-to-make-jmdns-work-on-a-large-network/18288491#18288491)

Comment: As of April 2019, the following link contains the javadoc for the latest version found on github: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.jmdns/jmdns/3.5.5